# Alert Box doesn't fit with screen in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm using alert box, that doesn't fit to my device screen. Especially width, i can increase the height by adding empty view, but i couldn't increase width. It always have some empty space on left and right side.

I don't know exactly whether it is android's default property or re-sizable. I've also tried custom alert box but it doesn't work for me. This alert box will update progress and show until progress complete.

This my code:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sync_dialog, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

        alertBuilder.setView(view);

        alertBuilder.setCancelable(false);

        AlertDialog progress = alertBuilder.create();

        // Dialogs set their Window's top level layout width and height to WRAP_CONTENT. 
        // To make the Dialog bigger, you can set those parameters to FILL_PARENT.

        progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        progress.setCancelable(false);

        progress.getWindow().getAttributes().width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        progress.getWindow().getAttributes().height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        mProgress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);


        /*Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.sync_dialog);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


        mProgress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);*/

        mText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);

        //Rebuilds ProgressBar with saved state when closed

        if (!firstTime) {

                mText.setText(mCurrentStatus);

                mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);

        }

        mProgress.setMax(mProgressMax);         



        return progress;
```

Layout File is:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/body"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
    android:paddingRight="8dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip" >


     <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/btn_mfa_home"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mfa_icon_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"         
        /> 



    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/btn_sync_home"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_sync_home"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"         
        /> 


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dip"
        android:text="@string/dialog_initial_syncing"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />




    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="240dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you are not `setting the attrbutes on the dialog`

something like this might help

```
 AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Dialog d = adb.setView(new View(this)).create();
    // (That new View is just there to have something inside the dialog that can grow big enough to cover the whole screen.)

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(d.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    d.show();
    d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Note that the attributes are set after the Dialog is shown. The system is finicky about when they are set.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried , but it doesn't work.  I have shown this alert box using DialogFragment class like this FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();DialogFragment df = new SyncDialogFragment();  df.show(ft, "sync_dialog"); so i can't use .shoe method inside that one i posted.

Answer (score 0):

try using LayoutParams

```
mDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where to add this code ? addition i used fragment class to show the alert box. FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();DialogFragment df = new SyncDialogFragment();   df.show(ft, "sync_dialog"); Inside SyncDialogFragment class i have my alert box code above pasted.

Comment: may be after this line `alertBuilder.setCancelable(false);` in your case mDialog=alertBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I help, alone use it after yourAlertDialog.show()

`alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);`